# Not printing a value make's it behave weird

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, simulation

To start, sorry for the not-so-descriptive tittle, I really don't know how to call this problem, so let's start...

I have to designe an AI for a 4x4x4-4 in line game and we're using Monte Carlo method to do this AI, so basically I have to make a simulation of the posible moves of the computer n-times and determine which next move is the best posible, our professor gave us some base code to play a 4x4x4-4 in line game and we had to designe the AI so here is my method to simulate the AI:

**EDIT1: Added full program.**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random
from copy import deepcopy
import time


board = [
  [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
  [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
  [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
  [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
  ]
]

p1_token = 1
p2_token = -1
draw_token = 0
pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)


def slice_winner(state_slice):
  slice_size = len(state_slice)
  sums = [sum(row) for row in state_slice]
  sums.extend([sum([row[i] for row in state_slice]) for i in range(slice_size)])

  if (p1_token * slice_size) in sums:
    return p1_token
  elif (p2_token * slice_size) in sums:
    return p2_token

  return 0

def winner(state):
  for state_slice in state:
    winner_in_slice = slice_winner(state_slice)
    if winner_in_slice != draw_token:
      return winner_in_slice

  state_size = len(state)

  for i in range(state_size):
    state_slice = []
    for j in range(state_size):
      state_slice.append([state[j][i][k] for k in range(state_size)])

    winner_in_slice = slice_winner(state_slice)

    if winner_in_slice != draw_token:
      return winner_in_slice

  diagonals = [0, 0, 0, 0]
  for i in range(state_size):
    diagonals[0] += state[i][i][i]
    diagonals[1] += state[state_size - 1 - i][i][i]
    diagonals[2] += state[i][state_size - 1 - i][i]
    diagonals[3] += state[state_size - 1 - i][state_size - 1 - i][i]

  if (p1_token * state_size) in diagonals:
    return p1_token

  elif (p2_token * state_size) in diagonals:
    return p2_token

  return draw_token

def str_token(cell):
  if cell == p1_token:
    return "X"
  elif cell == p2_token:
    return "O"

  return "."

def draw_board(state):
  result = ""
  state_size = len(state)
  for y in range(state_size):
    for z in range(state_size):
      for x in range(state_size):
        result += str_token(state[x][y][z]) + " "
      result += "\t"
    result += "\n"
  return result

def isInVector(vector, x, y, z):
  n = 0
  while (n < len(vector)):
    if (vector[n][0] == x and vector[n][1] == y and vector[n][2] == z):
      return True
    n += 1
  return False

def getInVector(vector, x, y, z):
  n = 0
  while (n < len(vector)):
    if (vector[n][0] == x and vector[n][1] == y and vector[n][2] == z):
      return n
    n += 1
  return -1

def getBestPlay(vector):
  max_value = -100000
  index_of_max = -1
  for i in range(len(vector)):
    if (vector[i][3] > max_value):
      max_value = vector[i][3]
      index_of_max = i
  return [vector[index_of_max][0], vector[index_of_max][1], vector[index_of_max][2]]

def AISim(main_state, p1x, p1y, p1z, maxIt):
  n = 0                 # Number of simulations
  p2Moves = []          # A vector to hold player 2 moves.
  while (n < maxIt):    # While 1
    x = p1x
    y = p1y
    z = p1z
    player_turn = False   # False because simulation will always start with player 2 turn
    moves = 0
    first_move = [0, 0, 0]
    new_state = deepcopy(main_state)
    while winner(new_state) == draw_token:            # While 2

      temp = new_state[x][y][z]
      while temp != draw_token:         # While 3
        x = random.randint(0, 3)
        y = random.randint(0, 3)
        z = random.randint(0, 3)

        temp = new_state[x][y][z]

        # THIS IS THE PROBLEEEEEM!!!!
        print (temp)

      # END while 3

      if (moves == 0):
        first_move = [x, y, z]
        if (not isInVector(p2Moves, x, y, z)):
          p2Moves.append([x, y, z, 0])
        # END if
      # END if

      new_state[x][y][z] = (1 if player_turn else -1)
      player_turn =  not player_turn
      moves += 1
    # END while 2

    if (winner(new_state) == 1):
      temPos = getInVector(p2Moves, first_move[0], first_move[1], first_move[2])
      p2Moves[temPos][3] -= 1
    else:
      temPos = getInVector(p2Moves, first_move[0], first_move[1], first_move[2])
      p2Moves[temPos][3] += 1
    # END if-else

    n += 1
  # END while 1

  return getBestPlay(p2Moves)


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------- MAIN PROGRAM -------------------------------------------------
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

AIMove = [0, 0, 0]

player_1_turn = True
while winner(board) == draw_token:

  # Print board state
  print ("")
  print ("Board:")
  print (draw_board(board))
  print ("")

  # Print 
  print ("Player %s turn:" % (1 if player_1_turn else 2))

  if (player_1_turn):

    # Get input
    x = int(raw_input("x: "))
    y = int(raw_input("y: "))
    z = int(raw_input("z: "))
  else:
    # Player 2 turn
    start = time.time()
    AIMove = AISim(board, x, y, z, 500)
    end = time.time()
    print ("Thinking time: %0.4f seconds" % (end - start))
    x = AIMove[0]
    print ("x:",x)
    y = AIMove[1]
    print ("y:",y)
    z = AIMove[2]
    print ("z:",z)


  if board[x][y][z] == draw_token:
    board[x][y][z] = 1 if player_1_turn else -1
    player_1_turn = not player_1_turn

  else:
    print ("")
    print ("ERROR: occupied position, please retry in a new position")
    print ("")

print ("Player %s is the winner!" % (1 if winner(board) == 1 else 2))
```

And the code works I've test it many times and all, the problem is in the "While 3", for an unknown reason SOMETIMES the code may get stuck in a somewhat infinite loop regardless of the state of the board, like if there were no posible (x, y, z) coordinates that make the loop end, but I know there're! Because for the same unknown reason if I place a `print (x, y, z)` inside the loop, the AI work perfectly 100% of the times, but wait, there's more! As you might notice by printing (x, y, z) inside that loop make's the final output horrible, so I try `print(x, y, z, end='\r)` (I'm importing `from __future__ import print_function`) and it didn't work, the same weird behavior again, I've try so many things but the only solution seems to be printing the values I've been trying for hours and I need help, please!

You can test the program [here](https://ide.c9.io/cor14095/testpython).

My list of fail trys:

- Save (x, y, z) in another array. It worked if I printed the vector...
- Writing in an eternal file the coordinates, the coordinates were saved correctly, but it didn't fix it.
- Assigning the random values generated to other variables and then those variables to the x, y and z.
- Printing only 1 or 2 values, like x and z.
- Swap x, y and z values.

**EDIT2: Added a link to c9 so you can test it.**

**EDIT3:** If you run it in your PC you might want to change the number of simulations, because printing over 1000 simulations might feel like it is infinite, but it isn't. Try printing like 100 or 300 simulations it might take a while but you'll see it working, then try like 1000 without printing(time should be the same since printing takes so much time) and you'll see it doesn't work.

**EDIT4: Removed threading code.**

**UPDATE:** I don't need this anymore for an assignment, I solve it in other way not using this code, but I really want to know what is happening and why does the print make's the program work or not.

*P.S. Sorry again if it's somehow unclear what is happening, but I don't really know how to explain it better than this.*

Comment: If your program bugs sometimes, I don't see how a print statement could make it work all the time. You probably just got lucky. Or we need to see a [mcve]...

Comment: @JulienBernu I know, that's why I'm so shocked and don't know what to do, let me set up an environment so you guys can test it and see it with your eyes.

Comment: you run this function in threads - maybe they have access to the same `new_board` and one thread mess result of other thread.

Comment: So how are we supposed to replicate your bug? I've tried the code as is and it seems to go into infinite loop even with the print statement...

Comment: @furas You can take of the thread, even with out it it behaves weird.

Comment: Right. I added x,y,z in the print and it seems to work. How weird...

Comment: @Julien Bernu Were are you trying it? I've notice that sometimes it take's to much time to print all values, so it might seem to be infinite loop, but it isn't, but if you print (x, y, z, temp) and add a delay, you can see that the temp value does make it the correct to exit the while.

Comment: I think furas is right: strange behaviour comes from multi-threading. Remove multi-threading and it seems like your program stalls not matter what you print... Looks to me like your program is bugged and another bug from not handling multi-threading side effects correctly might somehow 'help' it out of infinite looping...

Comment: @JulienBernu I kinda understand what you're telling me but I don't think it's the case since the thread can be removed and the "main bug" will still happen.

Comment: @AlejandroCortes:  If "the thread can be removed and the 'main bug' will still happen", then all that threading code is a distraction from the bug you're asking us to find.  Please [edit] your question to provide the _non_-threaded version, which would be one big step closer to a [mcve].

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Edited.

Comment: My observation holds with your edited code: with or without print the program bugs. So as expected printing x,y,z is completely disconnected from your problem. And I don't understand what is still puzzling you...